# What do you call a curve that resembles a crooked S

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

but it is tilted about theta=artan(x) wit the upper half of the '8' removed about the midpoint and the lower part removed about the of other half.
It looks like a tilted 'S' but flipped, and it's monotonically increasing or decreasing.

[image: function/curve]

Comment: You mean $\propto$ or $\sim$?

Comment: $\int$ ? The description could use work

Comment: the second one, but it reaches a maximum-->minimum or minimum->maximum at the endpoints.

Comment: Are you asking about a mathematical symbol for writing, or a geometric shape for drawing?

Comment: i made a picture to clarify http://i.imgur.com/i6TgFpI.png  to one extreme (letting a variable go to infinity) it looks like half a swastica and to the other extreme a diagonal line. It's like two superharmonic functions with the top function an inverse of the other.

Comment: If you wonder about a $\LaTeX$ character that you've not seen before, try drawing it on [this page](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html). Detexify will usually present you with several options.

Comment: Is it possibly the [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's $\theta = \arctan{x}$,

[image]

Also note that the *sigmoid function* is a mathematical function having an "S" shape ("aka": a sigmoid curve). Often, the sigmoid function refers to the special case of the *logistic function*:

$y = \dfrac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}$

[image]

---

If you are looking for the "reflection" or "inverse" of a "tilted $S$-shaped curve:

The inverse of $\;\theta = \arctan(x)\;$ is $\;x = \tan(\theta),\;$ and when plotted you get what you might be looking for if you restrict $\theta$ to $\theta \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$:

$x = \tan(\theta),\; \theta\in \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$

[image]

Somewhat similarly, what you seem to be describing (a reflected/flipped tilted "S") looks a bit like the simple cubic function: $y = x^3$, (the graph can be translated, or rotated to tilt it more.)

$y = x^3$

[image]

Comment: How did this not get any thumbs-up? +1

Comment: $\ddot\smile$. I am at the uni.

Answer (score 2):

a sigmoid function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function. It has lots of applications in natural science, e.g., biological populations driven by evolution/natural selection.

Answer (score 1):

It is also called the logistic curve.

Another curve that looks much like it
is the $\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-t^2} dt$.